# python: pandas read_csv and german umlaut (ä,ö,ü) in filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, pandas, filenames

The following code

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\exampleä\\test.csv')
```

thows an

```
OSError: File b'C:\\example\xc3\xa4\\test.csv' does not exist
```

Is there a way i can use german umlaute like 'ä,ö,ü' in filenames with pandas.read_csv?

Surprisingly, this

```
df = pandas.read_excel('C:\exampleä\test.xlsx', 'test')
```

works perfectly.

Comment: Does it work if you pass a raw string: `df = pandas.read_csv(r'C:\exampleä\test.csv')`

Comment: No, it throws the same error.

Comment: What OS and python are you running, I just managed to open a text file that had an umlaut in the name fine on windows 7 64-bit using python 3.3.5 64-bit

Comment: I am using windows 7 64-bit and python 3.3.5 64-bit (WinPython).

Comment: it looks like a bug in `pandas`. 1. It should preserve Unicode filenames on Windows. 2. And I doubt that `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` is `utf-8` on Windows. If `open(r'C:\exampleä\test.csv', newline='')` is successful then [submit a bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues).

Comment: it works with pandas: 0.14.1, so the bug is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking at the python os module?  You may want to "parse" the path using that module when you pass it to the csv method and see if that works.  You can look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path

Viel Glueck!